# React native json stringify return my array correctly but it cannot show specific object in array

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

When I use `{alert(JSON.stringify(cart[0]))}` in my react-native app it shows me the whole array of object like this:

```
[{
  "id": 3,
  "name": John,
  .
  .
}]
```

but when I use `{alert(JSON.stringify(cart[0].id))}` for example it returns me `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided contains object with two nested arrays:

```
const cart = [
   [
     {
       id: 3,
       name: 'John',
       // ...
     }
   ],
]
```

When you try to receive value of `cart[0].id` you actually refer to `id` property of the second array. To extract the value you want use `cart[0][0].id`.

Comment: thanks alot....but how can i refer this items inot FlatList data?? i used to use const { cart } = this.props

Comment: According to the rules of StackOverflow you should to create new question and describe this exact problem (with FlatList) to let others answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: Also, please mark correct answers as correct (if they are) using a checkmark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer